# Script that groups backups by date then deletes files+folders older than X days

Tags: bash, scripting, backup, maintenance

We have 30 days of backups = 30 folders, the backup runs hourly so in each of these folders, there are 24 files in each folder.   We need to run a script that keeps the five latest dates of files.

For example, if today is June 30 and I run that script, it doesnt matter how many files are in the folders June 25, June 26, June 27, July 28, July 29 it will keep all five folders and only delete the folders from June 24 and older.

Would also be nice to skip folders that have data < 10kb incase a backup task created an empty zip file.

What I have been testing so far:

```
find /files/ -ctime +5 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\n" | sort -u -r | tail -n+5 | xargs rm -R

-ctime +5 = which files we want to expire created more than 5 days ago,
-printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\n" outputs the dates of the folders so we can sort them
sort -u -r = sorting the output so we can do tail
tail -n +5 = tail skips the 5 newest filegroups: grouped by date, not just 5 newest files
```

Is this logic correct?  I also need some kind of xarg to execute "rm -R" on the resultant list of "old backups".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that your `find` command finds all files, not just the folders. Add `-type d` to only find folders. To remove those folders, why don't you just add `-exec rm -rf "{}"` to the `find` command instead of this complicated pipeline? Another thought - you don't say which names those folders have, but my guess is that you encode the backup date in them. Would it not be easier to delete folders based on their names? Finally, what do you mean by "skip" - do you want to keep old folders if they have less than 10K in them?

Comment: Sorry, pretty new to scripting.  By 'skip' it shouldnt count those folders with blank zip files as real backups.  The problem would be that if the number of backups to retain is set to 5 days, and the last five days backups failed then we would have no backups.

Comment: Take a different approach then. Sort the backup directories by their name (if the name contains the backup date) or their timestamp (`ls -t`). Maintain a counter. For each directory with a valid backup, increment the counter. When the counter reaches 5, start deleting.

Comment: Hmm yes lets actually ignore the dirs, every backup is a zip file anyways.   What would be the easiest way to do this?  Lets go with just keeping the latest 10 backups that have a filesize > 100kb

Comment: Just replace "backup directory" with "backup ZIP file" in my comment. Make a list of all those files, sorted by their names (if the date is encoded in the name) or modification date, then as above.

Comment: `find -ctime` does _not_ match files by creation time. Perhaps you meant the more usual `find -mtime`, which matches on "last modified time"